# How do you keep an indeterminate progress bar from freezing?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

What good is an indeterminate progress bar that is frozen because of course its on the same thread? Is there a way to keep it running? Possibly multi-threading?

Comment: Answering as comment because I'm not sure about in WPF, but in I think there's a BackgroundWorker class that will execute the process that does all your heavy work and can send updates to update the progress bar. yeah, multithreading is probably the only way to do this. BTW, like the Marathon profile pic ;)

Comment: edit: intermediate != indeterminate

Comment: Aleph one actually, but thanks. :)

Comment: Close enough! Is that mailing list still active? Haven't checked in ages...

Comment: @Frustrated... All I know about is trilogyrelease.bungie.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was using a separate thread.  I didn't realize I could create multiple STA threads.  I created a simple delegate thread bubble that I pop whenever I want to hide the progress window.

```
protected void ShowProgress()
{
    if (_progressThread != null)
        return;

        _progressThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var progressShell = Program.ViewFactory.CreateDialogShell();
            progressShell.DataContext = new ProgressViewModel(this);
            progressShell.Show();

            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        _progressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _progressThread.Start();
}

protected void HideProgress()

{
    if (_progressThread == null)
        return;

    _progressThread.Abort();
    _progressThread = null;
}
```

Comment: You need to destroy that dispatcher when you're done with it by calling Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown on your _progressThread. Assuming progressShell is a window, you could do this in the Closing or Closed event.

Comment: Wow, this was so long ago. Today, I'd just keep all long tasks separate from the UI thread using the a Task and async / await.

Answer (score 1):

Threading is almost certainly the solution, yes - or asynchronous operations. You definitely shouldn't be performing a long-running task in the UI thread.

One common pattern is to use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the background task - it makes it particularly easy to report progress back to the UI thread.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker pattern is the exact opposite of what I need.  I need to display the progress bar in an alternate thread.  I can't just wrap my processes in a BackgroundWorker, because it is not my stuff that's taking a long time.  Its WPF layout that is taking the time.

Comment: @Jordan: It would have been helpful to explain that to start with. It's *possible* that you could create a new UI thread for a whole separate window - within a single window I think you're likely to have problems though.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to do. How?

Answer (score 0):

Code I've used in this situation

```
        ProgressIndicator.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;            

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
        (
            delegate
            {
                // Perform slow action
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    new Action(delegate()
                    {                                    
                            // Insert UI related activity here.
                            // ....
                            ProgressIndicator.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;                                                                     
                    }
                    ));
            }
        );
```

Comment: The slow action isn't mine.  Its WPF's layout that is taking forever.

Comment: I haven't had problems with WPF's layout being slow.  I presume you have some sort of recursive layout situation (or a very large number of controls). Can you give more info on the layout problem?

Comment: I have a list of a few hundred things that need to be put in a `ScrollViewer`.  I can't use virtualizing because the viewer needs to scroll smoothly as this is a touch screen application, and virtualizing forces integral scrolling.

Comment: Interesting problem, but you may want to add some detail to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the details of your problem but I had a similar-sounding problem (maybe?) where I had a ListView with many (hundreds) of thumbnails that needed to be displayed. The thumbnails were generated from digital photos on the file-system so creating that many thumbnails would have locked up the UI while they all loaded. I created all of the objects in the ListView with a placeholder image (tiny JPG with the string "Loading..."), and just enough data so that the background worker would then *update* each object in the ListView with the thumbnail, and possibly other data from the file (the data for the placeholder objects came from a simple database query). The user gets a UI that's responsive while the loading occurs. This worked well because loading the placeholder data for hundreds of objects was quick enough (a few seconds), compared to possibly minutes for very large sets of data. I don't know enough about your situation to know if this would work...